# Xcode compilation errors with external library (OSX program)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a simple "Hello world" type program in Xcode and I'm trying to use an external library in that, but I'm getting compilation errors. The library is the Magtek edynamo macOS sdk:

https://www.magtek.com/Content/SoftwarePackages/1000004036.zip

(parent page is https://www.magtek.com/support/edynamo?tab=software; download is the macOS SCRA SDK)

This is my code:

```
#import "MTSCRA.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MTSCRA* mtSCRALib = [[MTSCRA alloc] init];
    return 0;
}
```

So basically I'm just importing the library and trying to instantiate one of its classes. Xcode doesn't show any inline compile errors anywhere, but when I try to build and run, it results in a variety of undefined symbol errors such as this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification", referenced from:
      -[HIDManager init] in libMTSCRAOSX.a(HIDManager.o)
```

and warnings such as this:

```
ld: warning: object file (/path/HelloWorld/libMTSCRAOSX.a(MTSCRA.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.12) than being linked (10.11)
```

(If I comment out the `MTSCRA* mtSCRALib = [[MTSCRA alloc] init];` line, it runs fine.)

These are the steps I took to include the library in my Xcode project:

- I dropped the MTSCRA.h and libMTSCRAOSX.a into my project directory.
- From Build phases -> Link binary, I added libMTSCRAOSX.a.
- Build Settings -> Library search paths is set to "$(inherited)" and "$(PROJECT_DIR)/HelloWorld"

This is my environment:

- Macbook Pro 64-bit
- OSX El Capitan 10.11.5
- Xcode V8.2.1

Tried all the google solutions; nothing worked. Any help...can anyone else successfully import and use this library?

Comment: The warning says that the library is build for 10.12, but your system is running 10.11. Sure that you got the correct library version?

Comment: That's the only one they have.

Comment: Update: One error is that I also needed to include the library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd. After including that, I am left with just one compile error: the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Not sure if these are rookie mistakes, but I had two issues:

1) I also needed to include the library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.‌​platform/Developer/S‌​DKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/l‌​ib/libstdc++.6.0.9.t‌​bd

2) I also had to import `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`. So:

```
#import "MTSCRA.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MTSCRA* mtSCRALib = [[MTSCRA alloc] init];
    return 0;
}
```